# Need to check for the existence of an account if true skip if false create account

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to create local user on all servers and I want to schedule this as a scheduled task so that it can run continually capturing all new servers that are created.

I want to be able to check for the existence of an account and if true, skip; if false, create account.

I have imported a module called getlocalAccount.psm1 which allows me to return all local accounts on the server and another function called Add-LocaluserAccount 
which allows me to add local accounts these work with no problems

when I try and run the script I have created the script runs but does not add accounts

```
Import-Module "H:\powershell scripts\GetLocalAccount.psm1"

Function Add-LocalUserAccount{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName=$env:computername,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$UserName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Password,
        [switch]$PasswordNeverExpires,
        [string]$Description
    )

    foreach ($comp in $ComputerName){

        [ADSI]$server="WinNT://$comp"
        $user=$server.Create("User",$UserName)
        $user.SetPassword($Password)

        if ($Description){
            $user.Put("Description",$Description)
        }
        if ($PasswordNeverExpires){
            $flag=$User.UserFlags.value -bor 0x10000
            $user.put("userflags",$flag)
        }
        $user.SetInfo()
    }
}

$usr = "icec" 
$rand = New-Object System.Random

$computers = "ServerA.","ServerB","Serverc","ServerD","ServerE"

Foreach ($Comp in $Computers){
    if (Test-Connection -CN $comp -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet){ 

        $admin = $usr + [char]$rand.next(97,122) + [char]$rand.next(97,122) + [char]$rand.next(97,122) + [char]$rand.next(97,122) 
        Get-OSCLocalAccount -ComputerName $comp | select-Object {$_.name -like "icec*"} 
        if ($_.name -eq $false) { 
            Add-LocalUserAccount -ComputerName $comp -username $admin -Password "password" -PasswordNeverExpires 
        }
        Write-Output "$comp online $admin"
    } Else {
        Write-Output "$comp Offline"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother checking? You can't create an account that already exists; you will receive an error. And with the ubiquitous `-ErrorAction` parameter, you can determine how that ought to be dealt with, such as having the script `Continue`. Going beyond that, you can use a try-catch block to gracefully handle those exceptions and provide better output/logging options.

Regarding your specific script, please provide the actual error you receive. If it returns no error but performs no action check the following:

- Event Logs on the target computer
- Results of `-Verbose` or `-Debug` output from the cmdlets you employ in your script
- ProcMon or so to see what system calls, if any, happen.

---

*On a sidenote, please do not tag your post with v2 and v3. If you need a v2 compatible answer, then tag it with v2. Piling on all the tags with the word "powershell" in them will not get the question answered faster or more effectively.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do a quick check for a local account like so:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='true' and Name='Administrator'"
```

If they already exist, you can either output an error (Write-Error "User $UserName Already exists"), write a warning (Write-Warning "User $UserName Already exists"), or simply silently skip the option.

Please don't use -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue.  Ever.  It will hide future bugs and frustrate you when you go looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

This can very easily be done in one line:

```
Get-LocalUser 'username'
```

Therefore, to do it as an `if` statement:

```
if((Get-LocalUser 'username').Enabled) { # do something }
```

If you're not sure what the local users are, you can list all of them:

```
Get-LocalUser *
```

If the user is not in that list, then the user is not a local user and you probably need to look somewhere else (e.g. Local Groups / AD Users / AD Groups

There are similar commands for looking those up, but I will not outline them here